# How can I call a function on another controller in a different directory from a controller is another directory where just copying it will not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I know there are other solutions here... but my situation is kind of unique.

The first controller, and yes, this is in AngularJS for a huge telecom, has several unique $scope variables which cannot be moved or copied. This code is a MESS!

So, I've tried:

```
        $rootScope.CallMainFunction, (incomingData) => {
             $scope.mainFunction(incomingData);
        };
```

and the mainFunction is here... all complex but I've dumbed it down

```
$scope.mainFunction = (data) => {

    --- Do lots of stuff here with lots of variables NOT available anywhere else

}
```

The calling function:

```
$rootScope.$emit.CallMainFunction(id);
```

The two controllers are separated by two folders:

```
--- MODULES (just the name of the directory)
---| folder 1
---| folder 2
---| folder 3
---| folder 50 <-- YEAH there are this many.
```

I COULD make a service but this is such a dysfunctional app, it'll take weeks. That's the CORRECT way to do it "IF" I was in Angular 6 - 14.

So, I'm left with trying to call a function to a function within another controller. Thoughts please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'sending' controller is a parent of the 'receiving' controller (being that it's sent via $rootScope), you can broadcast the event down and then execute the function in it's own controller.

```
//broadcast the event down
$rootScope.CallMainFunction = function (someData) {
    $scope.$broadcast("callMainFunction", someData);
}
```

Then in the receiving controller, listen for the event. Also, don't forget to kill the listener when the controller gets unloaded

```
//handle SendDown event
var myListener = $scope.$on("callMainFunction", function (evt, data) {
    $scope.theMainFunction(data)
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', myListener);
```

Comment: No, there are no parent controllers. Each of the 50 modules have their own independent controller, service, and HTML Template.

Comment: OK, well, you're calling this from rootScope. There isn't a higher level than that. This should work, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it goes into the BROADCAST but never hits the SEND DOWN